# Getting an error when tried to install bower packages with jspm

Tags: github, npm, bower, jspm

When I try to install a bower package like **devextreme** with the following command **jspm install bower:devextreme**, I get an error

> Registry bower not found

Should I update any jspm settings or install any npm package to install bower packages? Both the npm and github works fine with jspm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [video](http://jspm%20registry%20create%20bower%20jspm-bower-endpoint) helped me. After installing the **jspm-bower-endpoint** package, run the command **jspm registry create bower jspm-bower-endpoint**.